# Randomly shuffle C++ array (different each time)

Tags: c++, arrays, random, shuffle

I want to shuffle an array in C++, and each time the program is run, I want to have a different random shuffling. I have `myArray` of length. Currently I am using:

```
random_shuffle(myArray, myArray+N)
```

but this produces the same shuffling every time. To include a random number, I tried:

```
random_shuffle(myArray, myArray+N, rand()%i)
```

but I get the error `cannot convert parameter 3 from 'int' to 'int&'`.

I considered using the `shuffle` function instead, based on [this example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle#Example), but it appears that I'm stuck using a pre-2011 compiler.

Sorry if this is an egregiously stupid question. I couldn't find anything for this particular issue on SO, and google just told me ways to create a shuffling algorithm.

Comment: There are no stupid questions, only questions. There was a time when I couldn't even walk.

Comment: [This link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/) is really good reference. Take a look at please

Comment: the type of `rand()%i` it's not a function or a callable object, take a better look at that example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`random_shuffle(myArray, myArray+N)` will use [`std::rand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) to obtain random numbers.  If you want the random sequence to be different each time the program is run you need to seed the random generator first using [`std::srand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand).  It is common to seed the random number generator using the current system time, which is usually good enough for non-security-related purposes.  You only need to do this once during your program's execution.

```
std::srand(std::time(0));
```

If you do not call `std::srand()` before the first time `std::rand()` is called, then `std::rand()` behaves as though you had called `std::srand(1)` -- that is, you implicitly seed it with the same value each time the program is run, which will produce the same random sequence each execution of the program.

Comment: To add to this: you normally need to call `std::srand()` only once in your program.

Comment: @moooeeeep Good point. I've incorporated that into my answer.